# Referenciar atributo de etiqueta html en css

Tags: html, css

Tengo un `textarea` con un atributo `placeholder="tu comentario"`. Me gustaria cambiar el color de dicho texto pero no se como referenciarlo en la hoja de estilos.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793639/change-placeholder-text-color-of-textarea

Comment: Hola Sergio, ¿puedes mostrar lo que has intentado y por qué no te funcionó? En las preguntas ha de mostrarse un intento o una investigacion al respecto, como buscar en el sitio.  Mira [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Hola Sergio. ¿Por qué crees que la pregunta debe reabrirse?  Si tienes dudas en el proceso o crees que el cierre es indebido, comprueba [Meta] o publica una pregunta con tus dudas. Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto

```
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: pink;
}
textarea::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
 color: pink;
}
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: pink;
}
textarea:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: pink;
}
textarea::placeholder { /* Default, admitido por la mayoría de navegadores modernos */
  color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! ;)

Comment: Hola @SergioAG . Por favor, evita comentarios como el que has puesto aqui ya que aqui se sigue un [código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct). El usuario que te dejó un **comentario** te referenció una informacion util. **No** era una respuesta.  Edito tu comentario para omitir esos apelativos innecesarios. Un saludo

Comment: Hola D! Gracias por responder. Para que tu respuesta tenga más calidad intenta no solo poner el codigo y *"prueba con esto"* si no explica tambien el funcionamiento de los selectores y psudoelementos de css. Mira [answer]  para más info. Además, como es un lenguaje web, puedes usar un **snippet de codigo** para demostrar visualmente su funcionamiento :D Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Me remito a [este interesante artículo publicado en CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/), donde se analiza tu caso a fondo:

El pseudo-elemento `::placeholder` (o una pseudo clase, en algunos casos, dependiendo de la implementación del navegador) permite aplicar un estilo al texto del marcador de posición de un elemento del formulario.

Puedes aplicar estilo a ese texto en la mayoría de los navegadores con esta selección de selectores con prefijo de proveedor:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: red;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: red;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: red;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="tu comentario"></textarea>
```

Al igual que cualquier psuedo, puedes incluir elementos específicos según sea necesario, por ejemplo en caso de querer colores distintos según el tipo de elemento, la clase, etc:

```css
textarea.red::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="normal" placeholder="tu comentario"></textarea>
<textarea class="red" placeholder="esto irá en rojo"></textarea>
```